# Template processing - find variable references inside a string

Tags: java, regex, string

I'm building a very trivial template processor. It will only be able to substitute values of variables.

I thought I would first decompose the string into parts (constant parts and variable references). I would then replace all variable references with the corresponding values. Finally I would concatenate all the parts back together.

---

In order to decompose the string, I would need to slice it in the following way.

A string like this

```
"UPDATE {ix:tablename} SET value = value + 1 WHERE {ix:column} = {ix:value}"
```

should result in  the following array

```
[
  "UPDATE ",
  "{ix:tablename}",
  " SET value = value + 1 WHERE ",
  "{ix:column}",
  " = ",
  "{ix:value}"
]
```

I know this could be done by repeatedly searching for the first opening bracket, and then the first closing bracket, aso. But isn't there a more elegant solution than that (some regexp magic, perhaps?).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the array you want with a regex split:

```
MyString.split("(?=\\{ix:)|(?<=\\})")
```

<sub>(The `{` and `}` need to be escaped as `\{` and `\}` to be literal in regex, and because it's a Java string those `\`s needs to be further escaped as `\\`.)</sub>

i.e. Lookahead for `{ix:` or lookbehind for `}` and split at that position if either found.

If it is possible for `}` to be valid in other contexts, I would probably take a different approach.

### Lookarounds

An often forgotton aspect of regex, particularly when it comes to splitting, is that it can match **positions**, also known as zero-width matches.

Most people are familiar with positional matches, like `^` and `\b`, but fewer are well acquainted with lookarounds, which allow ad-hoc conditions to be specified.

When a regex contains only positional matching constructs, although there are no characters included in the match, regex still records the *position* where the match occurred - most string operations just need a position and a length, and a length of 0 still allows a split (or replace) to occur at the designated position.

Lookaheads and lookbehinds allow you to match positions by specifying sub-expressions which are checked going forwards (ahead) and backwards (behind) in the string from the position they are being tested at.

In syntax terms, a lookahead looks like `(?=subexpr)` whilst a lookbehind looks like `(?<=subexpr)`.

There are negated versions - for when the pattern must fail to be considered successful - which are `(?!subexpr)` and `(?<!subexpr)` respectively.

Lookarounds are non-capturing - their match is *not* placed in backreference groups like a standard `(group)`, though they can contain backreferences.

#### Lookbehind Restrictions

Lookbehinds in Java* have a restriction that they cannot be unlimited length - so you can't do `(?<=\w+)` but instead need to use numeric quantifiers with an upper bounds, e.g. `(?<=\w{1,99}`

<sup>(*A couple of regex implementations don't have this restriction; though many have a stricter restriction of being fixed length.)</sup>

Lookaheads do not have such a restriction (though of course for performance reasons you should limit them to matching only what is required).

Comment: Excelent! Thank you. I will accept your answer in 10 minutes.

Comment: Wow! Frankly speaking, I don't understand how `?=` and `?<=` work. Can you elaborate a bit on this, or maybe give some link to read? Thanks.

Comment: Andrew, I'll add a proper explanation to the answer in a moment, but in brief they match a position (i.e. between characters) where their sub-expression is true. Also, the `(?<=`..`)` goes backwards and must be limited length (can't use `*` or `+` quantifiers)

Comment: Andrew, I've added an explanation to the answer - let me know if it makes sense or if clarification needed?

Comment: @PeterBoughton Thanks, it does. I didn't receive any notifications (you didn't use `@<nickname>` notation), that's why I read it only now. I didn't know that such a cool thing exists :)